# Problem with DataTemplate and ObjectDataProvider refresh

Tags: wpf, datagrid, combobox, templates, objectdataprovider

I have a problem with a edit templete of cell in a WPF datagrid (WPF Toolkit). The template is builded with a ComboBox and the ItemsSource of
ComboBox are loaded at runtime.

This is the mean code...

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataValuesProvider" MethodName="GetValues" />

<toolkit:DataGrid
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems}">
<toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn
  Header="Property1">
    <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Property1, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
         <ComboBox
            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Property1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
            IsEditable="True"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataValuesProvider}, Mode=OneWay}"
            />                                        
          </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn></toolkit:DataGrid>
```

Now, I have this problem.

I have to update the dataValuesProvider with different value on each rows. Then I have insert a reset of dataValuesProvider (dataValuesProvider=null) on selectionchanged event of datagrid.

(The dataValuesProvider will load after a input on a specific cell of the selected row).

This is the problem: when I reset the dataValuesProvider (on selectionchanged of a new row) it's modified the SelectedValue of ComboBox and the Property1 of previous row is cleared.

I think that there is this behavior becouse the editing template of cell not update the binding associations until I edit the cell. It's right?

How can I do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet resolved

however I have defined a simple project that show the problem.

You can download it from this link: http://pollosky.it/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/ObjectProviderTest.zip

Try to selectvalue from the second cell of the first row and then go to the second row. The value of property of first row is cleared!

How can I do?

Comment: Anyone? Any informations or opinions about this problem is useful for me...what do you think about?